# C# parsing error, cannot find due to line not existing?

Tags: c#, parsing, mono

I'm coding a tic tac toe game in C#
anyways, i keep getting this parsing error for line 57, however i have no line 57.
here is the code? can anyone help me?

i use mcs for my compiler, and here is the warning.

```
game.cs(57,1): error CS8025: Parsing error Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

and this is the code.
*hosted on pastebin*
http://pastebin.com/ft1FkDqU

can anyone tell me how to fix this?
help is appreciated!
also, if you see any other problems, please tell me?

Comment: Since it's showing the error being 1 line past the end, it's possibly a missing `}` somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
        if(move == 0){board[0, 0] = "x";
        if(move == 1){board[0, 1] = "x";
        if(move == 2){board[0, 2] = "x";
        if(move == 3){board[1, 0] = "x";
        if(move == 4){board[1, 1] = "x";
        if(move == 5){board[1, 1] = "x";
        if(move == 6){board[2, 0] = "x";
        if(move == 7){board[2, 1] = "x";
        if(move == 8){board[2, 2] = "x";
```

You have an open brace { all those line.

Edit:

You can remove all those IF with this single line:

```
 board[ Math.Floor(i/3.0), (i%3) ] = "x";
```

Comment: If the main question is answer you need to check the answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing curly brackets of the if statements :

> if(move == 0){board[0, 0] = "x" ; \ clsoing bracket here }

P.s it would be better not to have the starting curly brackets any ways since the
syntax:

if (boolean ) statement;

or

> if (boolean)
>
> statement;
>
> is valid anyways..

With this change it should compie and run

Comment: ok, that got fixed, thanks for the help, however, now the while loop goes through twice, like i enter input, then it goes through again without asking for input, then on the second loop, it asks input again. also, my code is supposed to edit the board and display an x, but it doesn't do that, any reason why? here is the messed up code. (same paste edited code) *http://pastebin.com/ft1FkDqU*

Comment: thats not it, my problem is that even after fixing, the code doesn't show an x here it's supposed to on the next loop. so this is the output of a sample run. *http://pastebin.com/jTrucEwJ* first of all it does not ask for input on the second time, and it does not show the x in the middle for the second time either. any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Game
{ // declares the class
    private static string[,] board = new string[3, 3]{
                                              {" ", " ", " "}, // top row
                                              {" ", " ", " "}, // middle row
                                              {" ", " ", " "}  // bottom row
                                          };


    private static void print()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("\n {0} | {1} | {2} ", board[2, 0], board[2, 1], board[2, 2]);
        System.Console.WriteLine("------------");
        System.Console.WriteLine(" {0} | {1} | {2} ", board[1, 0], board[1, 1], board[1, 2]);
        System.Console.WriteLine("------------");
        System.Console.WriteLine(" {0} | {1} | {2} \n", board[0, 0], board[0, 1], board[0, 2]);
    }

    private static void calculateMoves()
    {
        System.Console.Write("The possible moves are: ");
        int n = 1; // this is used to list all possible moves.
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (board[i, j] == " ")
                {
                    System.Console.Write("{0} ", n);
                }
                n++;

            }
        } // end print possible moves.

        System.Console.WriteLine(); // go to next line

    }
    static void Main()
    { // the main function, the program starts from (this is a method declartion)
        System.Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to theelitenoob's simple tic tac toe game!");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Written in C#, released under the GPL.");
        System.Console.WriteLine("The board is 3 by 3, Type a number to place a move there.");
        System.Console.WriteLine("So 1 is bottom left and 9 is top right, like a standard keypad.\n");
        int winner = 0; // there is no winner yet.
        // write players piece
        System.Console.WriteLine("You are x");
        // create the board

        int move;
        print();
        calculateMoves();
        System.Console.Write("Please type in a move number: ");
        while (winner == 0 && int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine() , out move) )
        {
            move--;
            if (move == 0) board[0, 0] = "x";
            if (move == 1) board[0, 1] = "x";
            if (move == 2) board[0, 2] = "x";
            if (move == 3) board[1, 0] = "x";
            if (move == 4) board[1, 1] = "x";
            if (move == 5) board[1, 1] = "x";
            if (move == 6) board[2, 0] = "x";
            if (move == 7) board[2, 1] = "x";
            if (move == 8) board[2, 2] = "x";

            print();
            calculateMoves();
            System.Console.Write("Please type in a move number: ");


            /**/
        } // end while loop
    }
}
```

This should work now though u need to do validation checks etc... P.S better to use bool instead of string in array and bool for the while condition as well